# Change User Password Form

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to create a form that will change the current user id password.

i have to mention that i have the sessios user_id

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["user_id"]) || $_SESSION["user_id"] == "") {
```

the table name is : system_users

and system_users contains:

```
u_userid | u_username | u_password | u_roldecode
   1          admin       admin      SUPERADMIN
   2          user1       user1pw     ADMIN
```

i have tryied many forms to change the password but none working :(

could you please help me? i would really apreciate your effort!

Thank you!

Comment: Well, what have you tried thus far? Can you provide me some code? We need start somewhere.

Comment: Follow the simple logic. Use a normal html form to ask the user to enter the new password. After certain validation, e.g. entering the password twice to match, POST the new password with User ID (from hidden input field). Use the SQL UPDATE query WHERE user_id matches to change it. Try something in this direction and edit your question with your tried code in case you face any issues.

Comment: i got no ideea where to start :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP Section:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // put your connect server, select database code below.

    // the below code checks if the user_id is set.
    // If it is set, store it in a variable named $user_id
    // and grab the old password for display.
    if(isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
        $user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM system_users WHERE u_userid = '$user_id'";
        // replace $connect with the variable you used mysqli_connect();
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $SQL);
        $field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $oldpass = $field['u_password'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['change'])) {
        $newpass = $_POST['newpass'];
        $SQL = "UPDATE system_users SET u_password = '$newpass' WHERE u_userid = '$user_id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $SQL);
        // redirect to some page after changing password
        header("Location: thephpfile.php");
    }
?>
```

HTML Section:

```
<form name="changepass" action="thephpfile.php" method="post">
    <input type="password" name="newpass" placeholder="New Password" value="<?php echo $oldpass; ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" name="change" value="Change Password"/>
</form>
```

Replace thephpfile.php to the name of your php file. The two codes are to be written on the same php file.

Comment: Can you show me what outputs you are getting then? Do you have your connections and selections completed?

Comment: everything works as aspect, but he does not change the password, could you be more precisley how session_start should look like?

Comment: You don't need to do more with session_start, but with it, you are able to check if the session variables such as your user_id variable is set or not. The connection and selection variables should be placed under the session_start, check here for how to do it by Shankar Damodaran's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20407699/php-connect-to-mysql-database.

Comment: dammit i cant make it to work :( i got no ideea whats wrong

Comment: Do you mind if you send me a jsfiddle or codepen of what your code looks like so I can see what is going wrong? You can put the PHP in the HTML and I will use your code to copy and paste to mine so I figure out what errors or anything you are getting.